# How to switch to different default database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two different connection set in the database config file. Once I have connected to the one of the database if I connect to the second database still the connection is not changed. I am getting table not found error.

```
$this->load->database(); //connecting to default db
$this->db->query('SELECT * from user'); //user table in default db and no error

$this->load->database('second_db');//connecting to second db
$this->db->load('SELECT * from statistic'); //table exists in second db but getting error
//The same work if I comment the first two lines
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403177/how-to-switch-database-in-codeigniter?rq=1 ?

Comment: @cornelb Actually I want to change the default database connection ($this->db) not trying to get the second connection parallel in another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made it work myself.

```
$this->load->database(); //connecting to default db
$this->db->query('SELECT * from user'); //user table in default db and no error

$this->load->database('second_db',FALSE,TRUE);//connecting to second db
$this->db->load('SELECT * from statistic'); //table exists in second db but getting error
//The same work if I comment the first two lines
```

The only change is when loading the second database need to pass two extra parameters. 
First one FALSE - Don't return connection object
Second TRUE - Change the Active record to the loaded DB

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way :

```
$this->load->database('second_db', TRUE);
```

and also set FALSE for 'pconnect' in database.php :
for default one:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

and for second one:

```
$db['second_db']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: @Nish have tried this way for default database load: $this->load->database('default', TRUE);

Comment: Worked for me using:

    $second_db = $this->load->database('second_group',TRUE,FALSE);


Making the group constant:

    $db['second_group']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$this->load->database('second_db', TRUE);
```

You have to use like

```
$db = $this->load->database('second_db', TRUE);
```

Because the second parameter true return you the the full object 
Now the $db is your db object you might assign the $db to a class variable

```
$this->second_db = $this->load->database('second_db', TRUE);
$this->second_db->query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked for me using **Codeigniter 2.1.0**:

```
$second_db = $this->load->database('second_group',TRUE,FALSE);
```

Making the group constant setting 'pconnect' as:

```
$db['second_group']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```